# Is the following a subspace of $P_3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

I am struggling with this question.  I know that I need to use the subspace test but I am stuck on how exactly to do so for this example:

Is the following a subspace of $P_3$?
$$U = \{xg(x) + (1-x)h(x) \mid g(x), h(x) \in P_2\}$$

(the set of $P$ consists of polynomials)

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What's the problem? I mean, where are you stucked?

Comment: Is it enough to say that the zero vector lies in U because g(x) ad h(x) are elements of $P_2$ ? or is there a specific way to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P_{2}$ be the vector space of all polynomials of degree $\leq 2$ over some field. If $a,b$ are scalars and if $g_{1},g_{2},h_{1},h_{2} \in P_{2}$, then 
$$
axg_{1}(x) + a(1-x)h_{1}(x) + bxg_{2}(x) + b(1-x)h_{2}(x) = x[ ag_{1}(x) + bg_{2}(x)] + (1-x)[ ah_{1}(x) + bh_{2}(x)].
$$
Upon noting that $ag_{1}(x)+bg_{2}(x), ah_{1}(x) + bh_{2}(x) \in P_{2}$, we are done.

Comment: How do you prove that 0 lies in U though?

Comment: Taking $a := b := 0$ suffices.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**:

$x(p(x)+q(x))+(1-x)(r(x)+s(x)) = (xp(x)+(1-x)r(x)) + (xq(x) + (1-x)s(x)), x(\lambda p(x)) + (1-x)(\lambda q(x))=\lambda(xp(x) + (1-x)q(x)), \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$